# Gradle task not found in root project

Tags: jenkins, gradle, gradlew

I'm using Jenkins to build a project. My build process is done through gradlew.

I set the gradlew location to:
`/var/jenkins_home/workspace/project/X/Y/Z/projectname/gradlew build javadoc`

My build fails with this error: `Task 'javadoc' not found in root project 'project'`.

This means that Jenkins is trying to execute my task from the directory `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/project/` instead of `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/project/X/Y/Z/projectname/`.

I don't understand how Jenkins is executing a task from the wrong directory. Any input on this issue is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where you run a program from is different from the active directory when you run the command. You need to set into the directory before you run the command. If you are using a freestyle job, I believe you would want to set the root directory to tell gradle where your build file is.

Comment: Right! I forgot to change the advanced gradlew configuration "Root Build script". Thank you :)